# SQL select multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question with SQL.

I have 3 tables, messages, payments and reports.

I want to get all events from a user from every table in one query, so this is wat I like to get:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = 10
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE client_id = 10
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE receiver_id = 10
```

But in 1 query.

Is this possible?

```
Table structures:
- messages
id
sender_id
receiver_id
type
text
created_at
updates_at

- payments
id
user_id
client_id
method
cost
status
text
created_at
updated_at

- reports
id
sender_id
receiver_id
text
created_at
updates_at
```

Comment: Use JOINS if all the three tables have relationship.

Comment: Please Show the table structure, sample data and expected result.

Comment: In the example, both receiver_id and client_id are equal to 10  -  is it safe to assume these values form the relationship between the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no relationships between the 3 tables then you can just use `UNION`.  It can be as simple as this:

```
SELECT receiver_id as event_id, event_name, event_description, event_timestamp FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = 10
UNION
SELECT client_id as event_id, event_name, event_description, event_timestamp FROM payments WHERE client_id = 10
UNION
SELECT receiver_id as event_id, event_name, event_description, event_timestamp FROM reports WHERE receiver_id = 10
```

This assumes there is a common set of columns across all tables that you are interested in.  If however the columns have differing names but contain the same data (and datatypes), then you can use `AS` to rename the columns in the query to achieve the `UNION`

```
SELECT receiver_id as event_id, col1 as event_name, col2 as event_description, col3 event_timestamp FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = 10
UNION
SELECT client_id as event_id, col_a as event_name, col_b as event_description, col_c event_timestamp FROM payments WHERE client_id = 10
UNION
SELECT receiver_id as event_id, col_x as event_name, col_y as event_description, col_z event_timestamp FROM reports WHERE receiver_id = 10
```

Keep in mind that `UNION` will eliminate duplicate rows in your dataset.  If this is not the behavior that you want then use `UNION ALL` instead (it will not eliminate duplicates).

Also keep in mind that if you column datatypes are not the same across the table then you will have to cast them to a common type.  Casting is highly dependent of your DBMS so make sure you use the correct methods to do so.

Comment: Why not `UNION ALL` instead?

Comment: @jarlh Depending on the requirements (which none were provided in the question) `UNION ALL` would work too.  It just depends if you want to include duplicates in the result set or not.  In my experience, I rarely want duplicates in these type of instances and I always default to `UNION` unless requirements specify otherwise.

Comment: @Mark Great! Be sure to "accept" or "upvote" the answers that helped you solve your problem.  This will enable you to contribute to the community and provide help to future users who stumble across your question (because they have a similar question).  There are lots of great answers to choose from!

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly straight forward providing receiver_id and client_id hold the same values:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` LEFT JOIN `payments` ON 
`messages`.`receiver_id` = `payments`.`client_id` LEFT JOIN `reports`
ON `messages`.`receiver_id` = `reports`.`receiver_id`
```

Comment: How come that table order?

Comment: Before the op modified his question it literally showed just the top section of `SELECT`. Now assuming they all store the same `id` this would work fine

Comment: I'd say full outer join instead. (If an id has payments but no messages...)

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you want, do you want to get all the data in 1 query, or do you need joins with them?

If you want all the data in one table you can just do this i think:

```
SELECT * FROM messages as M, payments as P, reports as R
WHERE M.receiver_id, P.client_id, R.receiver_id = 10
```

Else you need to show us some more details about the relationship

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union or Union All to concatenate the results sets of the 3 queries. However all 3 tables must have the same amount of columns for it to work. Post your tables structure for a more exact solution.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = 10
Union All
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE client_id = 10
Union All
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE receiver_id = 10
```

Comment: Same number of columns - and matching data types!